# Cannot get the form values in redux form?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I'm creating a simple login form using react and redux form.
When I try to console the values entered in the form, I get undefined.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';`enter code here`

    class Signin extends Component {
      handleFormSubmit({email, password}){
        console.log(email,password);
        // this.props.signinUser({email,password});
      }

      render(){
        const { handleSubmit, fields: { email, password }} = this.props;

        return (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
            <fieldset className="form-group">
              <label>Email:</label>
              <input className="form-control" {...email} />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset className="form-group">
              <label>Password:</label>
              <input className="form-control" {...password}  />
            </fieldset>
            <button action="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
          </form>
        );
      }
    }

    export default reduxForm({
      form: 'signin',
      fields: ['email', 'password']
    })(Signin);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

The tutorial I was following was one year old and was using an old version of Redux Form which accepts input in this form. But while installing the modules, I installed the latest version. Thanks.